# adding vaadin ui to existing java web app

Tags: java, vaadin

I am working to create a UI using Vaadin, now I want to add this to an existing java web app.
Do I simply need to add the Vaadin jar file, and the java files of vaadin to that web app?

Or is there some procedure to follow, when doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to ensure that the Vaadin ApplicationServlet is being called, and is being sent the right requests. The VAADIN directory has theme information; you need to ensure it is being served as well, or is being served from the code base directly.

See the Book of Vaadin for details on how to configure your web.xml to ensure the right things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the vaadin.jar file to your WEB-INF/lib directory <strike>and you're good to go.</strike>

edit: see Ross Judson's answer.